# Python 3.3.2 how to convert .pgm to .jpg?

Tags: python, image, converters

How to convert .pgm image to .jpg? I tried with import Image and from PIL import Image but I haven't those libraries. I search but cannot find PIL for 3.3.2

**EDIT**
Thanks, answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3) question solve my problem

Comment: Hmm. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270700/how-to-write-pil-image-filter-for-plain-pgm-format) help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image library for Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3)