# how to convert PBM file to list/array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following PBM file (ASCII encoding) and I need to put each line (excluding `P1`,`#feep.pbm`,and`24 7`. Through a series of functions.

```
P1
# feep.pbm
24 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have seen several advice by changing them to list or numpy array for convinience. But the problem is how to do this in Python? I found about a similar solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270700/how-to-write-pil-image-filter-for-plain-pgm-format but it does not work on my case.

Comment: Could you upload this file in somewhere?

Comment: you can see the file in [my repository](https://github.com/alvin7bdi2214/quantum-teleportation-main). File name is `feep.ascii.pbm`.

Comment: How about handing it as string?

Comment: I couldn't even open it.

Comment: So you want to get an array of arrays where each array contains each line?

Comment: can you open this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvin7bdi2214/quantum-teleportation-main/master/feep.ascii.pbm? I tried handling it as string but its inconvenient. @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: I was trying to do that here @Countour-Integral

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is just use list slice.Try code below:

```
from pprint import pprint

with open("feep.ascii.pbm", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    arr = []
    for line in lines[3:]:
        t = list(map(int, line.strip().split()))
        arr.append(t)

pprint(arr)
```

Or with an easy list comprehension:

```
from pprint import pprint

with open("feep.ascii.pbm", "r") as f:
    arr = [list(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in f.readlines()[3:]]

pprint(arr)
```

All of them print:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```